# If statement with Pivot Table

Tags: excel-2007, excel-formula

I am trying to derive a formula which uses IF statements on pivot tables.

The goal is to perform IF functions on values when they do not EXIST. So far I have the following:

`=IF(GETPIVOTDATA("PO Outstanding Units",$A$2,"PO Horizon",0)=0,GETPIVOTDATA("PO Outstanding Units",$A$2,"PO Horizon","Past Due"),IF(GETPIVOTDATA("PO Outstanding Units",$A$2,"PO Horizon","Past Due")=0,GETPIVOTDATA("PO Outstanding Units",$A$2,"PO Horizon",0),(GETPIVOTDATA("PO Outstanding Units",$A$2,"PO Horizon",0)+GETPIVOTDATA("PO Outstanding Units",$A$2,"PO Horizon","Past Due"))/1000))`

The purpose of the formula is to see `IF "this pivot data" DOES NOT exist`, then `"Insert true value"`, then `IF "this DIFFERENT pivot data" DOES NOT EXIST`, then `"Insert true value"`, and the last false statement would be `if both pivot data DO exist`.

Basically, how do I make a formula which indicates whether a pivot table value exists or not?

Comment: do you define not existing as zero, blank, or both?

Comment: @SeanCheshire I define as blank as the value will never be zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are looking for to find items that don't exist is `ISBLANK`

This would make your example function look like this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(GETPIVOTDATA("PO Outstanding Units",$A$2,"PO Horizon",0)),
    GETPIVOTDATA("PO Outstanding Units",$A$2,"PO Horizon","Past Due"),
    IF(ISBLANK(GETPIVOTDATA("PO Outstanding Units",$A$2,"PO Horizon","Past Due")),
        GETPIVOTDATA("PO Outstanding Units",$A$2,"PO Horizon",0),
        (GETPIVOTDATA("PO Outstanding Units",$A$2,"PO Horizon",0)+GETPIVOTDATA("PO Outstanding Units",$A$2,"PO Horizon","Past Due"))/1000
    )
)
```

If you need to check if a column exists, then MATCH will check that, and give an error if it doesn't exist, so, to test if **Past Due** is a column name, then

```
ISERROR(MATCH("Past Due",$A$2:$F$2,0))
```

will return **TRUE** if the column is *not* found (Adjust the $A$2:$F$2 to your pivot column name range)

Comment: Hm, I believe the problem I am having is sometimes the "Past Due" isn't within the table AT ALL. The isblank would only work if "Past Due" was an actual value on the pivot table. Am I right?

Comment: MATCH is what can be used to check for a title

Comment: The range of the pivot table is always changing so for the column range I used `("A:A")`. When I am testing to see if it finds "Past Due", when TRUE (Which means column is NOT found), I am not getting a numerical answer back. I am getting `#N/A`.

Comment: you would need to use a row range to check the titles of columns, such as `("2:2")`, as the column names are across the top of the table. I have also fixed the test, as it should be **ISERROR**